# How to calculate interval in 30 minutes between two dates?

Tags: php

I have for example:

```
$first = '2014-05-18 12:00:00';
$last = '2014-05-18 13:30:00';
```

and i would like calculate interval in 30 minutes for these dates.
For this example interval = 3.

Other example:

```
$first = '2014-05-18 11:00:00';
$last = '2014-05-18 14:00:00';
```

interval = 6;

How is the best way for this in PHP?

Comment: Look over to the right under "Related" >>> you might find something there. Plus, you will find many results via Google, which will most likely lead you back here on SO, from Q&A's already asked and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple math solution

```
$s=floor(abs(strtotime($first)-strtotime($last))/30/60);
```

Here is fiddle
https://eval.in/153120

Answer (score 0):

```
function timeDiff30minutes($first,$last){
    $first = new Datetime($first);
    $last = new Datetime($last);
    $time_diff = $first->diff($last);
    $time_diff_minute = $time_diff->days * 24 * 60;
    $time_diff_minute += $time_diff->h * 60;
    $time_diff_minute += $time_diff->i;
    return $time_diff_minute/30;
}
timeDiff30minutes('2014-05-18 11:00:00','2014-05-18 14:00:00') // output 6
```

Comment: thanks but i have on my server PHP 5.1 and function DateTime::diff()  not exists :(

Comment: PHP 5.1 is a bit old. It's better to upgrade to PHP 5.3 or newer.

Comment: 5.1 hasn't been maintained since 2006.

Comment: Also this would return 2 for the top example given as your resolution is hours.

Comment: @stephan You're right.